# Possible permissions error with drush make

Tags: drush

I am trying to run drush make distro.make but getting the following error. The only thing I can see I did different was ran sudo drush make distro.make once. Any ideas?

> copy(/http---updates.drupal.org-release-history-drupal-7.x): failed to open stream: Permission denied drush.inc:840                                                                                                                [warning]
>
> Could not download project status information from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x                                                                                                                                                               [error]
>
> Non-existent project type  on project drupal

previously I was running without sudo and it was working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was that running sudo drush had probably added some unwanted permissions to the cache folder. Deleting the folder solved the problem.